# Changing nesting within an Angular 2 component template?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a user-configurable layout where I believe I would need to change nesting of elements per configuration. I don't want multiple templates, as this would be a chore to maintain, but I would like to know if there is some way in Angular 2 to define a parent element whose child elements will display weather or not the parent element is displayed. So if I have:

```
<parent>
    <child />
</parent>
```

I would like to use some sort of toggle to remove the `parent` element from the display list without losing it's `child`. So upon toggling off, `child` would become a child of `parent`'s parent.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

#### If `parent` is just an HTML tag, this can be accomplished indirectly using CSS classes that are applied conditionally.

For example, if `parent` is a `<div>`:

Template:

```
<span [class.myDivClass]="condition">
  <child />
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.myDivClass {
  display: block;
}
```

#### If `parent` is an Angular component, it may be easier just to add an input to it that disables its functionality instead of trying to un-nest it.

Alternately, it might be possible to create a directive that could have this type of effect.